# How to use drag feature in 2 layers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I used the following code:

```
this.installDrag({layer:this.poiLayer,opt:'load',id:'poiLatlong'});
this.installDrag({layer:this.addNewPoiLayer,opt:'add',id:'poiLatlong'});
```

but drag is installing for only for the last layer I call. How can I apply installDrag to more than one layer?

Comment: i had given an answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24682/3071)...`ModifyFeature` can solve your problem... i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Aragon answer was not working for me. I needed a solution so I spent a few days and found one that works:
[creating 2 dragable layers at the same time in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/creating-2-dragable-layers-at-the-same-time-in-openlayers#33107)

I hope that help!